# Linux script - user's real name

Tags: linux, scripting

Hello I am quite new in this, so I hope my question will be exact.

I need to write a script in Linux, which will write in output for every user who is logged in user's real name (5th column in /etc/passwd).

Output should look like this:

```
user1std James Brookes student
user2emp Jane Kowalski employee
.
.
...etc
```

Can you help, please?

Comment: Sure. Show your attempts first, though.

Comment: Hi, thx for noticing my question. I tried something like: $ who | sort | uniq But now I only trying to remember it becasue its on my laptop at work. I can send my other tries next morning.

Comment: Iam trying to match output from who (only 1st column) with (1st column) /etc/passwd and when it is the same then write cat passwd | cut -d: -f1,5   But cant make it running:{ Should I use variable as an output(1st column)??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous. Your text is asking for something else than what is sugegsted by your sample output.

This will print names:

```
finger -l | grep "Name:" | cut -d ":" -f 3 | cut -c 2- | sort | uniq
```

This will print logins and names (and I don't know what your last column is meant to be):

```
finger -l | grep "Name:" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f 2,4- | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your advice. But I cant use command finger. My opensuse 12.1 (gnome version 3.2.1) dont know it:(

Comment: Why don't you install it? It should be very easy.